# Scala not found: value macro

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, macros

This line:

```
"foo".assertNonFatal( _ equals "foo", "error message");
```

This error:

```
Error:(120, 47) not found: value assertion
```

This hook:

```
final implicit class ImplicitAssert[MyType](val me: MyType) {

  final def assertNonFatal(assertion: (MyType) => Boolean, message: String)
    : MyType = macro ImplicitAssertMacros.assertNonFatal[MyType]
}
```

This macro:

```
object ImplicitAssertMacros {
  def assertNonFatal[MyType](c: scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context)
      (assertion: c.Tree, message: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val me = q"${c.prefix}.me" // "me" from ImplicitAssert class.
    val numLines = q"Int.MaxValue"
    val useStdOut = q"false"
    val assertionTrue = q"assertion($me)"
    val isFatal = q"false"
    val toReturn = q"""
       _root_.info.collaboration_station.debug.internal.Printer.traceInternalAssert($message, $numLines, $useStdOut, $assertionTrue, $isFatal);
       $me;
    """
    toReturn
  }
}
```

^ I can't figure out what the cause of this compiler error is or how to fix it.

Note that it only happens when I compile the source file, not the macros.

Comment: Are you compiling the macro before, in a compilation session, before compiling the code that calls the macro?

Comment: @pedrofurla - running "compile" on the macros in sbt ends in [success]. Running "test:compile" for "foo".assertNonFatal( _ equals "foo", "error message") ends in "not found: value assertion"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works by changing:

```
val assertionTrue = q"$assertion($me)"
```

A def macro expands at the call site, where there is no longer any assertion parameter.